How to solve $\int \frac{\sqrt{2-2\cos{x}+\cos^2{x}}}{3-2\cos{x}} \mathrm{d}x$?
Does anyone know how to solve this integral?
$$y=\int\frac{\sqrt{2-2\cos{x}+\cos^2{x}}}{3-2\cos{x}} \mathrm{d}x.\tag{1}$$
I got it while I was computing the development of an oblique cone (equation $(1)$ is the case where $h=1$ and $d=1$). If I plug it in WolframAlpha I get quite a mess: I wonder if it can be simplified with the assumption that the domain is the real numbers.
Thoughts?

I do not think that you could avoid elliptic integrals of the first, second and third kinds.

@ClaudeLeibovici that I understand but why does the solution have complex numbers in it?

Too long for a comment.
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)}}{3-2\cos(x)} \,dx$$
Using the tangent half-angle substitution and then partial fraction decomposition
$$I=\int \frac{2 \sqrt{5 t^4+2t^2+1}}{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(5   t^2+1\right)} \,dt$$ $$I= \frac52\int \frac{\sqrt{5 t^4+2 t^2+1}}{ 5
   t^2+1}\,dt-\frac12\int\frac{\sqrt{5 t^4+2
   t^2+1}}{t^2+1}\,dt$$ So, you face two integrals looking like
$$J(a,b,c)=\sqrt 5 \int \frac {\sqrt{(t^2-a)(t^2-b)}}{c\, t^2+1}$$ where
$$\large\color{red}{(a,b)=-\frac {1 \pm 2i}5}$$ This is why complex arguments appear in the elliptic integrals of the first, second and third kinds.
Have a look here for the result before simplifications.
If the link is broken, just give Wolfram Alpha
Integrate[Sqrt[(-a + t^2)*(-b + t^2)]/(1 + c*t^2),t]

Many things I don't know that I'll delve into. Merci beaucoup Claude!!!

@fab. Don't worry ! There are so many things to learn (say $\infty$). I know less than $\epsilon$ after 65 years of professional experience. Cheers :-)
